# require imports differently if array destructuring is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, require, module.exports

I detected this error while producing a create-react-app.

I tried producing a sample of my code via [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-butterfly-4peqe) to show others but I can't reproduce the same error. In the codesandbox sample folder, one of the properties of test1.js uses array destructuring. I was expecting an output like displayed on codesandbox but instead my code outputs something similar to

```
test0: Object
  t0: function t0() {}
  t1: function t1() {}
test1: Module
  __esModule: true
  Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
  __proto__: Object
  type: "test1"
```

I was able to resolve it by not using array destructuring but I want to know why there is a difference. Same browser was used. Same react-scripts version. FYI, I use `module.exports` since this also code needs to be used on the server.

Comment: Check your cache, indexedDB/localStorage - error is not reproducable.

Comment: @Zydnar Cleared cache / localStorage but its not the problem. Also, ran it on a incognito page just in case.

Comment: So maybe it's browser addons connected issue?

Comment: @Zydnar None are active in incognito mode.

Comment: `I can't reproduce the same error` - if problem does not exist any more why do you care? Noone can repreduce problem, because in console `test0` and `test1` outputs are the same I tried in different browsers. `Cleared cache / localStorage` - but what about indexedDB? BTW such bugs happen regularly at codesandbox because of something inside indexedDB.

Comment: @Zydnar I can produce the bug on my app, just not on Codesandbox. I couldn't identify where the bug could be originating from. I'll try playing my app till I figure it out. I think one of the JS libraries may be modifying things it shouldn't. It could even be security risk.